# Universal Abelian Covering Space of genus two surface

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let M be a surface M, i am concerned with Abelian covers. These are the
covering spaces for which the deck group is Abelian. The largest such cover corresponds to the commutator subgroup of the fundamental group , in which case the deck group is the homology group.

I would like to know how to construct it for a genus two surface.

Comment: Take the Cayley graph of $\Bbb Z^2$, so an infinite graph with vertices the lattice points $\Bbb Z^2$, but think of it inside $\Bbb R^3$. Take the boundary of a tubular neighborhood of this graph.

Comment: This is more of a statement than a question, and does not really invite an answer.

Comment: @MikeMiller I don't understand in which way the group of decks could be $\mathcal Z^4$

Comment: You're totally right, I apologize. You might try following [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/237734/98602) but with a basis of curves, instead of just the two.