# First Cohomology of Abelian Cover

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, covering-spaces

Let $S$ be a closed oriented surface. Consider the (universal) abelian cover $p \colon S_{ab} \rightarrow S$, i.e. the one whose group of deck transformations is the abelianization of $\pi_1(S,\star)$. My professor told me that $H^1(S_{ab},\mathbb{R}) = 0$. Even more so, he said the abelian cover is the smallest cover for which the first cohomology group vanishes.

EVEN NEWER EDIT:

Here is what I have; I would appreciate any feedback as to correctness of the following arguments.

First of all, $H_1(S,\mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}^{2g}$ ($g$ the genus), so that by the universal coefficients theorem $H_1(S,\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^{2g}$.
Thus, the kernel of the Hurewicz map $\pi_1(S) \rightarrow H_1(S,\mathbb{Z})$ is the same as the kernel of the map $\pi_1(S) \rightarrow H_1(S,\mathbb{R})$ and, hence, there is no ambiguity as to which map we use (this refers to one discussion in the comments).

Next, the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(S)$ is free and for genus $g \geq 2$ is not trivial (let us focus on the higher genus case).
Therefore, $$H_1(S_{ab},\mathbb{Z}) \cong \pi_1(S_{ab})^{ab} \cong [\pi_1(S),\pi_1(S)]^{ab}$$ is free-abelian (and not trivial).
Let us write this group as $\bigoplus_{j \in J}\mathbb{Z}$, where $J \ne \emptyset$.
Then $$H_1(S_{ab},\mathbb{R}) \cong H_1(S_{ab},\mathbb{Z}) \otimes \mathbb{R} \cong \bigoplus_{j \in J} \mathbb{R}.$$
Finally, $$H^1(S_{ab},\mathbb{R}) \cong Hom\big(H_1(S_{ab},\mathbb{Z}),\mathbb{R}\big) \cong Hom\Big(\bigoplus_{j \in J} \mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}\Big)$$ and this group is non-trivial.
In conclusion, it seems that the proposed statement in the question is not correct as stated.

EVEN NEWER EDIT THAN THE PREVIOUS EVEN NEWER EDIT:

Sooo, it took me a while to get back on MSE, but here we go again... My professor admitted to accidentally claiming a wrong statement. As verified above, the first cohomology of the abelian cover is often non-trivial. He corrected himself and now claimed that the induced map $p^* \colon H^1(S,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow H^1(S_{ab},\mathbb{R})$ by pull-back is trivial. Unfortunately, I still don't know how to prove this. I hope my endless amounts of edits have not yet tired you out.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}$, the universal coefficient theorem tells you precisely that you can compute cohomology in terms of homology, at least the first one (you also know $H_0$)

Comment: You're right that $\pi_1(S_{ab})$ is the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(S)$, and $H_1(S_{ab})$ is actually the *abelianization* of $\pi_1(S_{ab})$. If you can show that the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(S)$ is perfect then you can conclude that $H_1(S_{ab})$ vanishes, and hence also $H^1(S_{ab})$ by the universal coefficient theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions thus far. @William $\pi_1(S)$ can be presented with $2g$ generators ($g$ the genus) and 1 relation, so its deficiency is $2g-1$. If its commutator subgroup is perfect, then lemma 1.1 [here](http://www.math.nus.edu.sg/~matberic/jonhAJB03306.pdf) tells us that the deficiency of $\pi_1(S)$ is at most 1. Hence, only for genus $g=0,1$ can the commutator subgroup be perfect. What can we do in the case $g\geq 2$?

Comment: The more I think about it the less sure I am that your professor's statement about cohomology is true. If $H^1(S_{ab}; \mathbb{R}) = 0$ then $H^1(S_{ab};\mathbb{Z})$ is either trivial or a torsion group, but since $S_{ab}$ is a covering space of an oriented surface it also has to be an oriented surface and the constraint on cohomology means that it has to be a sphere or the plane, and both of these have the wrong fundamental group (should be the commutator subgroup of $\pi_1(S)$ which is not trivial in general). Are you sure you have the right statement? (I might just be confused.)

Comment: For example the answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/233360/abelian-covering-space-of-surface-of-genus-g) shows the desired abelian cover for $\Sigma_3$, and it appears that the first cohomology for this space should not be $0$.

Comment: Thanks again! I looked up his statement again and, strictly speaking, he said that he defines the abelian cover as the cover whose fundamental group is the kernel of the Hurewicz map $\pi_1(S) \rightarrow H_1(S,\mathbb{R})$. He took coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$ for this Hurewicz map, but I didn't think it would make a difference. Either I am wrong and this is not the same as the Hurewicz map into $H_1(S,\mathbb{Z})$, or he made a mistake himself.

Comment: This is definitely not the same ! You abelianize and tensor  by $\mathbb{R}$ instead of just abelianizing

Comment: I know it is different in general, but isn't $H_1(S,\mathbb Z)$ free here? In that case, there isn't much difference.

Comment: Is it OK that I cast the question into a new light in terms of a more general algebra question or should I have opened a new question for this?

Comment: This post: https://chiasme.wordpress.com/2014/08/27/on-subgroups-of-surface-groups/ proves that the commutator subgroup of a surface group is free (I don't know a better reference). In this case, the original statement is false.

Comment: Thanks for the reference! But I am sort of lost know since my professor insisted that "$H^1(S_{ab},\mathbb{R}) = 0$" is true. Did I use an incorrect argument when I made the reduction to the torsion property of $\pi_1(S_{ab})^{ab}$?

Comment: Here is a proper reference (given in the post above): https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/stillwell1x.pdf see 4.2.2 on p.142 for the heart of the matter. It follows that $H^1(S_{ab},\mathbb R) \neq 0$, it is rather free on the number of free generators of the commutator subgroup.

Comment: Thank you :) I will have a look.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the result is true for a sphere and a torus; with higher genus, you can prove that the fundamental group is not abelian.

Comment: As a final thought: for higher genus, the "smallest" (in the sense of what, I'm not sure, but in this case it is the only one) cover of $S$, $X\to S$ that has $H^1(X,\mathbb R) = 0$ is $X=$ the universal cover of $S$, which is contractible.

Comment: For the new edit, the commutator subgroup maps trivially into the abelianization of a group. It follows that the induced map on $H_1$ is trivial, and then you get the result by universal coefficients again.

Comment: @JustinYoung that turned out easy, thank you very much! :)